# Returning the first model after a find

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Given:

```
App.Chart = DS.Model.extend({
  pastCharts: function() {
    var id = this.get('id');
    return this.store.filter('chart', function(q){
      return q.id < id;
    });
  }.property()
});
```

Instead of returning an array I'd like to return just the first item. I tried

```
return this.store.filter('charts', function(){}).get('firstObject');
```

and

```
return this.store.filter('charts', function(){}).then(function(s){
    return s.get('firstObject')
});
```

Which doesn't get rendered out correctly in my template, so I appear to be confused about something.

Basically I want this to work:

```
{{chart.pastChart.id}}
```

Comment: can you add the related route and controller, or may be an isolated fiddle with those. `filter` returns a `FilteredRecordArray` which is updated automatically using observers. The automatic updation wont be working for the element once you take an element out of it. Also you have to explain "doesn't get rendered out correctly" and make it clear what is happening.

Comment: you can as well try `}.property('id')` if your `pastCharts` is getting calculated before `id` is set. It has no observers and will never be calculated again.

Comment: @sabithpocker It's not getting calculated before the model has been set. Basically `filter` works fine and returns the `FilteredRecordArray` that gets rendered out fine if I do `{{#each chart.pastCharts}}{{this.id}}{{/each}}`, but I don't want an array I just want the first item.

Comment: and what is happening when you get `firstObject` from that working result?

Comment: A failing bin would help.